# If then elseif then wrong statement excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me please. I have the below code, if i have only if statements without else if, the code works fine but if i write elseif case then nothing works right. For example, if i type a product that is on Catalogue sheet and i want to change it, it shows that the product doens't exist and if i try to add the same product it enters.  Except from this the message boxes are shown 2 times. For example if i add a new product it show 2 times "Do you want to add product?" but the product added only 1.

```
Dim t1, t2, t3, t4
Dim arrayData As Variant
Dim arrayData2 As Variant
Dim cleanData As Range
Dim keli As Range
Dim baseSheet As Object
Dim formaSheet As Object
Dim Stock As Object
Dim meter As Long
Dim meter2 As Long
Dim Movement As String
Dim i As Integer


    Set Stock = Sheets("StockMovements")
    Set baseSheet = Sheets("Catalogue")
    Set formaSheet = Sheets("DataEntry")
    Set t1 = formaSheet.Range("A6")
    Set t2 = formaSheet.Range("B6")
    Set t3 = formaSheet.Range("C6")
    Set t4 = formaSheet.Range("D6")

    Movement = Range("E6").Value

 If Movement Like "ADD NEW" Then

 For i = 2 To 10000


    With Worksheets("DataEntry")
    If (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
    Then
       MsgBox "The product already exists. Try to change it", vbOKCancel
    ElseIf (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
    Then
             MsgBox "Do you wnat to add new product?", vbOKCancel
             meter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(baseSheet.Range("A:A"))
             meter2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Stock.Range("A:A"))
             arrayData = VBA.Array(t1, t2, t3, t4)
             Set cleanData = Union(t1, t2, t3)

             With cleanData.Cells
              Set keli = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
              If keli Is Nothing Then
              GoTo telos
              End If
             End With

             baseSheet.Cells(meter + 1, 2).Resize(, 4) = arrayData
             Stock.Cells(meter2 + 1, 2).Resize(, 4) = arrayData
             cleanData.ClearContents
    End If


End With
Next i

End If



If Movement Like "CHANGE" Then

 For i = 2 To 10000


    With Worksheets("DataEntry")
    If (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
    Then
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "C") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "D") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C")
         Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "E") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "D")

         Worksheets("StockMovements").Cells(i, "C") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "B")
         Worksheets("StockMovements").Cells(i, "D") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "C")
         Worksheets("StockMovements").Cells(i, "E") = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "D")
    ElseIf (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(6, "A"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Catalogue").Cells(i, "B")))) _
    Then
        MsgBox "The product does not exist. Select add new and then continue", vbOKCancel

    End If
End With
Next i
Set cleanData = Union(t1, t2, t3)

With cleanData.Cells
 Set keli = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
 If keli Is Nothing Then GoTo telos
 End With

cleanData.ClearContents
End If

telos:

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure `ElseIf` is necessary here. You test a condition equals something with your `If` statement. Then your `ElseIf` tests if that condition equals everything else. This is redundant as the `If` test already takes care of this, if the `If` is false, your other test will always be true, so a simple `Else` alone will do.

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger and step thru the code (F8)?

Comment: @FunThomas let me try that and tell youu.

Comment: @Plutian with elseif or with only else it does exactly the same.

Comment: @FunThomas Well....i see that it comes in a loop, for every i it shows the message prodcut doesnot exist and when  i is number of product_row then does the change or the add and then keep counting, next next next. Did you understand what i mean? Sorry for my englilsh